# Where to position `import` modules inside an class?

Tags: python

I define a class with multiple `methods` using standard library.

```
 class Dostuff:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def read_book(self):
        import os
        pass

    def listen_music(self):
        import os.path
        pass

    def ask_question(self):
        import glob
        pass
```

Where is the suitable place inside a class?

The class will be used as a module for repeated application.

Comment: Don't use a class as a module. Use a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand the scope of `import` .
Firstly, It's PEP practice to put module on the top,
secondly and most importantly, it's not about best practice,it works that way.
Every time You import any `class` or `function` from your file (or module) 
`import **`run ahead always.

Answer (score 1):

It is good custom to place all your imports at the top of your file. There is a style guide on imports in PEP-8.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

In your case:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import os.path
import glob

 class Dostuff:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def read_book(self):
        pass

    def listen_music(self):
        pass

    def ask_question(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) on imports:

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

Answer (score -1):

Usually the best practice for importing any type of module is to do it at the top of the file you are writing in. So in your case it would look like this:

```
import os
import glob

class Dostuff:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def read_book(self):
        pass

    def listen_music(self):
        pass

    def ask_question(self):        
        pass
```